# What is ATTOcelebrity.kext?

Tags: high-sierra, kernel-extensions

I scanned my Mac for viruses using a nice open source GUI app called "KnockKnock" which was pretty useful to remove some unnecessary binaries from apps which I had deleted a long time ago.

But KnockKnock also reports some kernel extensions. I have a SAT Smart driver installed so I know that kext but the other seem to be doubtful and I have a feeling that they might be some type of malware. However clicking the 'info' button reports that it is developed by ATTO Technologies and sited by Apple CA, However I am still doubtful:

[image]

Is it genuine?

Answer (score 3):

ATTOCelerityFC8.kext is a driver for some [ATTO fibre channel](https://www.atto.com/products/fc-adapters) cards. They fit in some pre-"trash can" Mac Pros only.

ATTO explicitly lists all Mac compatible adapters here: [Apple Solutions](https://www.atto.com/solutions/apple/), but forgot to update the list for High Sierra.

There is no real doubt that the driver is genuine.

The ATTO**Celebrity** kext is some figment of imagination only ;-)